# Getting Error when opening document from document Library in sharepoint2013

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, file-extension, sharepointdocumentlibrary

User has full control to the Document Library and also the items in the document Library. When the user is try to open file (excel or word or pdf) from the Document Library. It is showing an error with the file name as showing below. But When the user download it to desktop and opening it from there it works fine.

[image]

Thanks in Advance for your helps. Anyone, could you please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Upload other files to document library with variety of formats : imgs, pdf excel and word. and see if same issue persists..

Comment: I am getting the same error.